# How does similarity_search_with_score() calculate the scores while retrieving the most similar document from embedding

Tags: huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers, py-langchain, openaiembeddings

I am trying to retrieve most similar documents based on question and i am getting top_k =5 docs.
but, How does similarity_search_with_score() calculate the scores while retrieving the most similar document from embedding.

I want to know the mathematics behind the similarity_search_with_score() method.also need to understand how they re-rank documents based or score.

Answer (score 1):

According to the LangChain [documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/faiss?highlight=FAISS.from_documents#similarity-search-with-score), the method `similarity_search_with_score` uses the [Euclidean (L2) distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to calculate the score and returns the documents ordered by this distance with their corresponding scores (distances).

There is no additional re-ranking as you are suggesting, the method returns the same *top k* documents as the simpler method `similarity_search`. The difference is that the score (Euclidean distances between the query and the documents) is also returned.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic similarity search methods would typically return the n most similar results, which are defined as the five samples that are closest to the input vector. Closeness can for instance be defined as the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or [cosine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between 2 vectors.

To scale such a similarity search, you will need some kind of indexing algorithm upfront. IVF and HNSW are two popular ones that you will find in most vector databases. [This blog](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/series/faiss/vector-indexes/) explains it very well.